# Is "magasin" a false cognate or a false friend to "magazine"?

Tags: anglais, faux-amis

Our teacher said that "magasin" was a false cognate to "magazine" (which obviously does not mean store), but Wikipedia confuses me with the terms false friend and false cognate. Which is it?

Please do not respond in French as I just began learning it, thanks.

Comment: False cognate and false friend mean the same thing, no? Also, people will always respond in language the question was written in.

Comment: @bronxbomber92 False cognates and false friends are **not** the same thing. But FL is not the place to discuss about it and the issue has an answer on [linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2612/whats-the-difference-between-a-false-cognate-and-a-false-friend).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **False cognates** and **False friends**

> - **False cognates** are words that are similar in their modern forms despite having different etymologies. This is regardless of whether the modern meanings are similar.
> - **False friends** are words that are similar in their modern forms despite having different modern meanings. This is regardless of whether the words are etymologically connected.

(Part of an [extensive answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2613/637) that was given on Linguistics Stackexchange.)

*Magasin* and *magazine* are in no way false cognates because they have the same etymology (English *magazine* comes from French *magasin*).

You could say that *magasin* and *magazine* are false friends because they look the same, they could be pronounced the same (at least by an English native  who mispronounces French) but they have different meanings.

## **Magasin** and **Magazine**

French ***magasin*** came into French in the 14th century, from Arabic *maḫzan* meaning a warehouse. The word evolved into meaning as well the contents of the warehouse/store.

The English borrowed the word around the end of the 16th century. The word was also used in English<sup>1</sup> in the title of books with the sense of *A storehouse of information on a specified subject*<sup>2</sup>.

It was first used in English with the sense of a periodical publication containing articles by various contributors for general readers with the spelling ***magazine*** by then more or less stable, in 1731 for the title of the *[Gentleman's magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gentleman%27s_Magazine)*
And the word came back into French as ***magazine*** by the end of the 18th century first to designate English magazines, and then any type of magazine.

<sub>1 I do not think it ever did in French.</sub>
<sub>2 Ref. OED.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**False friends** are word that look similar between languages so that you might be tempted to use them with a meaning they only have in a different language. They are more a language learning/psycholinguistics concept.

**False cognates are** an issue of historical linguistics. They are words that look like they are etymologically related because of similar meaning and form, but have different origins.

False friends are an issue between languages. False cognates may occur within a language, for example *isle* (from Latin *insla* via middle French *isle*) and *island* (from old English *iegland*) have virtually no etymological connection although they look very similar and are synonymous.

Your teacher seems to have confused these concepts because *magazine* (both the French an English words, which are certainly not false friends to each others!) in fact **is etymologically related** to the French *magasin* and is certainly not a false cognate!